# SGD, calculating it by hand

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

While I find a lot of material of SGD (Stochastic gradient descent), I am struggling to find one concrete example with numbers e.g. calculating it by hand for let's say, one iteration would help me a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the following link examples in Numpy of the following optimisers

- Stochastic Gradient Descent
- Stochastic Gradient Descent + momentum
- Stochastic Gradient Descent + Nesterov momentum
- Adagrad
- Adadelta
- RMSProp
- Adam
- AdaMax
- Nadam

Just clone the repository and open the `Report.ipyb` with Jupyter Notebooks.

https://github.com/ivallesp/awesome-optimizers

Comment: Here is a new one for you, RAdam: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03265v1.pdf :)

Comment: Yes i saw it!! It looks awesome. I’ll consider implementing it. Or feel free to implement it and submit a pull request!

Comment: thanks a lot, cool viz stared. But was rly looking for a example where it is done for once by hand and with the math, seems to be non existing on the internet :(